# Yaourt: limiting output (ignoring AUR? RegEx?)

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, regular-expression, yaourt

I'm really enjoying `yaourt` to search for packages, except then `yaourt` just tries to ddos me, displaying like 1,000+ packages for some searches...

How can I effectively limit the output length?

For example: sometimes I know that the packages I search for are **not** in the `AUR`. How can I tell `yaourt` to ignore `AUR`?

Additionally the `man` tells me that I can `yaourt [regexp]` for some package. How can I use this to limit the search results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only *searching* for standard (non AUR) packages, then you can simply use `pacman`. This will search for packages only in `core`, `extra` and `community`. (When searching `yaourt`'s only additional functionality is to search `aur`)

You can then install these packages with `yaourt` if you like.

If you really want to use `yaourt` for searching, you can also filter with grep, of course:

```
yaourt --color -Ss query | grep '^\S*[ce]\w*/' -A1
```

Explanation:

- `--color` forces colorized output (would be normally gone, as it detects its output goes to a pipe)
- The `\S*` skips the escape-codes used for colouring, and ensures only the package names are matched (package descriptions always start with four spaces)
- The `[ce]\w*/` matches the prefixes `core/`, `extra/` and `community/` in front of package names, but nor `aur/`
- The `-A1` switch also prints the package description in the line following the match

Answer (score 0):

Try piping the command to `less`.I don't have Arch to test but here is how it do it with **dmesg** (or any other command).

```
dmesg | less
```

Use the arrow keys to scroll and <kbd>q</kbd> to quit.You can also press <kbd>h</kbd> to view help for the command